# Delete xml tags variables in xml file with C#

Tags: c#, xml, tags

I have xml file that has tags `<File>` I need to delete some variables and its values from these tags. `version="$(Version_Infralution.Common.dll)">Infralution.Common.dll` and all variables versions and its values. How can I do it in C#?

Part of XML file contents:

```
 <File version="$(Version_Infralution.Common.dll)">Infralution.Common.dll</File> 
 <File version="$(Version_Infralution.Common.dll)">Infralution.Controls.dll</File>
 <File version="$(Version_Infralution.Common.dll)">Infralution.Controls.VirtualTree.dll</File>
 <File size="73728">Infralution.RichText.dll</File>
 <File version="$(Version_Interop.DSOFile.dll)">Interop.DSOFile.dll</File>
 <File version="$(Version_NLog.dll)">NLog.dll</File>
```

Sample result:

```
 <File>Infralution.Common.dll</File> 
 <File>Infralution.Controls.dll</File>
 <File>Infralution.Controls.VirtualTree.dll</File>
 <File size="73728">Infralution.RichText.dll</File>
 <File>Interop.DSOFile.dll</File>
 <File>NLog.dll</File>
```

XML file structure has a lot of child tags before  tag, ex:

```
<Products>
    <Product name="Connectors">
      <Registry>
        <Reg key="HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ScanJour\iBox\Install" value_name="SettingsEditorShortcuts" value="1" platform="x64" />
      </Registry>
      <SharedProductRef name="SharedProduct for: ModelBuilder Client, iBox Search, Connectors" />
      <SharedProductRef name="SharedProduct for: ModelBuilder Client, iBox Server\iBox Utilities, iBox Server, iBox Server\ADODBC Manager, iBox Search, Connectors\Connector Manager, Connectors" />
      <SharedProductRef name="SharedProduct for: SharePoint Server Add-on\Search Control Webpart, Connectors" />
    </Product>
    <Product name="Connectors\Connector Manager">
      <FileSystem>
        <Dir name="ProgramFilesX64" value="ScanJour\iBox\Common Components\ConnectorManager\">
          <File version="$(Version_CSScriptLibrary.v2.0.dll)">CSScriptLibrary.v2.0.dll</File>
          <File version="$(Version_Infralution.Common.dll)">Infralution.Common.dll</File>
          <File version="$(Version_Infralution.Common.dll)">Infralution.Controls.dll</File>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify XML easily with [LINQ-to-XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).  First parse the source document into an [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) object (you can load files with [`.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181.aspx), or process a string variable containing XML with [`.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345532.aspx)):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("/path/to/filename.xml");
```

You can remove the nodes you don't want by filtering for the specific nodes and using the [`.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357554.aspx) extension method (this example removes any element of type `<File>` that has an attribute `version` with an exact value of `$(Version_Infralution.Common.dll)` - you can chain multiple conditions if you want to validate other constraints as well):

```
xdoc.Descendants("File")
    .Where(x =>
        x.Attribute("version") != null &&
        x.Attribute("version").Value == "$(Version_Infralution.Common.dll)")
    .Remove();
```

Sample Result:

```
<Files>
  <File size="73728">Infralution.RichText.dll</File>
  <File version="$(Version_Interop.DSOFile.dll)">Interop.DSOFile.dll</File>
  <File version="$(Version_NLog.dll)">NLog.dll</File>
</Files>
```

---

You can also alter specific nodes, for example changing the contents of the node, or values of specific attributes, or removing attributes altogether - this example removes the `version` attribute from any `<File>` element having a version of `"$(Version_Infralution.Common.dll)"`:

```
foreach (var xn in xdoc.Descendants("File")) {
    if (xn.Attribute("version") != null &&
          xn.Attribute("version").Value == "$(Version_Infralution.Common.dll)") {
        xn.Attribute("version").Remove();
    }
}
```

Sample Result:

```
<Files>
  <File>Infralution.Common.dll</File>
  <File>Infralution.Controls.dll</File>
  <File>Infralution.Controls.VirtualTree.dll</File>
  <File size="73728">Infralution.RichText.dll</File>
  <File version="$(Version_Interop.DSOFile.dll)">Interop.DSOFile.dll</File>
  <File version="$(Version_NLog.dll)">NLog.dll</File>
</Files>
```

---

Finally, you can save the result to file with [`.Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345830.aspx):

```
xdoc.Save("/path/to/newfilename.xml");
```

Comment: The task is to remove only attributes versions and all their values. and leave tags files and their contents. So if i have line - <File version="$(Version_NLog.dll)">NLog.dll</File> i need to get line <File>NLog.dll</File>.

Comment: @Alexander: See update.  I added example code how to modify existing nodes to remove attributes with a `foreach` iterator loop.  There are intuitive methods to alter, remove, or add attributes, tags, and values very easily.

Comment: your solution is cool and helpful but solves different problem. i need to remove only version attributes and its values instead of removing whole tag containing attribute with specific attribute value

Comment: @Alexander: There's a lot of documentation out there on the methods and properties available in LINQ-to-XML.  You may have to explore and research a little bit, but this should get you on the right track.  In  fact, I wrote most of the code above by simply using Visual Studio Intellisense to see what methods are available, reasoning about what they do based on the name, and trying it out.  You can do that too.

Comment: i was looking into all that method and could not work it out:( will keep on trying...

Comment: i started to debug what you wrote. Unfortunately foreach (var xn in xdoc.Descendants("File")) does not loop through <File ....> attributes. It finds nothing...

Comment: Your code does not work because <File> attribute is far not the first attribute in xml document. so i need somehow to iterate through all tegs parent before getting to <File> tag. How can i do it???

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question (maybe someone needs this solution also)
Working code:

```
    String path = @"C:\iBoxProductValidator.xml";
    String pathResult = @"C:\iBoxProductValidatorResult.xml";

    XmlDocument configDoc = new XmlDocument();

    configDoc.Load(path);

    XmlNodeList projectNodes = configDoc.GetElementsByTagName("File");

    for (int i = 0; i < projectNodes.Count; i++)
    {
        if (projectNodes[i].Attributes["version"] != null)
        {
            projectNodes[i].Attributes.Remove(projectNodes[i].Attributes["version"]);
        }
    }

    configDoc.Save(pathResult);
```